# Is a good practice return a Promise which value is undefined when it's resolve?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have written a function that pipe data to a new file, my function returns a promise.

```
async pipeToNewFile(fileData: string): Promise<void> {
     const newFilePath = await this.createEmptyFile();
     const readStream = fs.createWriteStream(newFilePath);
     readStream.write(fileData);
}
```

Is this a good practice?

Comment: It's like having a function that doesn't return any data: it's fine. If you don't have any data to return then don't try to return something useless.

Comment: Every `async` function must return a `Promise`, this is what makes it `await`able. Unless you specify something different, an async function implicitly returns a `Promise<void>`. You can see this as "this is something async I have to wait for, but doesn't return any result"